# Google Sheets, stack report from multiple workbooks

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Goal: To stack data from 90+ google workbooks, all with the same sheet name, into the one master sheet for reporting

Info:
All worksheets have the same number of columns.
I have the following script but it does not run properly, I think the issue is with how I am caching / Pushing the data to the array before pasting to the output sheet.

I am trying to build an array then paste it in one go.

The tables I am stacking have 47 columns, unknown number of rows.
The part that opens the sheets is all working perfectly.

```
    // Get the data from the worksheets
    var indexsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Index");
    var outputsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Output");
    var response = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Current Cycle', 'Enter Cycle Name Exactly in YY-MMM-Cycle# format', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
    var CurrentCycleName = response.getResponseText()

    // Assign datasets to variables
    var indexdata = indexsheet.getDataRange().getValues();


    // For each workbook in the index sheet, open it and copy the data to a cache

    indexdata.forEach(function(row, r) {
            try {

                //open Entity specific workbook
                var workbookid = indexsheet.getRange(r + 1, 7, 1, 1).getValues();
                var Entityworkbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById(workbookid)

                // Open workhseet
                Entitysheet.getSheetByName(CurrentCycleName)

                // Add PR Data to cache - stacking for all countrys
                var PRDataCache = Entitysheet.getDataRange().push()




            } catch {}
  })
    // Set the all values of the sheet at once
        outputsheet.getRange(r + 1, 14).setValue('Issue Splitting Data') 
    Entitysheet.getRange(2, 1, PRDataCache.length || 1, 47).setValues(PRDataCache)

    };
```

[image: Index Tab]
This is the index tab where we are getting the workbookid from to open each file

[image: Output Tab]
This is the output file, we are stacking all data from each country

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of `but I cannot get it to work`? And, I cannot understand what you want to do in `forEach` in your script. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, I've given more detail.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Can you explain your 2 images? And, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Goal: To stack data from 90+ google workbooks, all with the same sheet name, into the one master sheet for reporting
Images description has been updated

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, you want to retrieve all values from the 1st tab of Spreadsheets retrieved from the column "G" of "Index" sheet, and want to put retrieved all values from all Spreadsheets to "Output" sheet. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, the order of columns in each Spreadsheet is the same in all Spreadsheet?

Comment: And, unfortunately, I cannot understand `Rename worksheet to current cycle` in your script. Because in your script, the sheet name is not changed. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: That was an error from an old script - Rename worksheet to current cycle - this has been removed

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Open every workbook in Column G, and then add the data from that sheet to an array, before pasting the output. 
All sheets will have exact same columns

Comment: Thank you for replying. How do you want to do about the header row of each Spreadsheet? For example, each Spreadsheet has no header row? And, the number of all columns is the same for all Spreadsheets? I apologize that I try to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243400/discussion-between-simon-hardham-and-tanaike).

Comment: We ideally would remove the header row from every sheet.
Same number of columns for all spreadsheets

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the Spreadsheet IDs from the column "G" of "Index" sheet.
- You want to give the specific sheet name using a dialog.
- You want to retrieve all values from the specification sheet in all Spreadsheets. In this case, you want to remove the header row.
- You want to put the retrieved values on "Output" sheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var indexsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Index");
  var outputsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Output");
  var response = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Current Cycle', 'Enter Cycle Name Exactly in YY-MMM-Cycle# format', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var CurrentCycleName = response.getResponseText();

  var ids = indexsheet.getRange("G1:G" + indexsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var values = ids.reduce((ar, [id]) => {
    try {
      var [, ...values] = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(CurrentCycleName).getDataRange().getValues();
      ar = [...ar, ...values];
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`"${id}" was not found.`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  
  // If the number of columns is different in all Spreadsheets, please use the following script.
  // var maxLen = Math.max(...values.map(r => r.length));
  // values = values.map(r => r.length < maxLen ? [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill("")] : r);

  outputsheet.getRange(outputsheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[1].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- When the number of Spreadsheet IDs is large, the processing time might be over 6 minutes. I'm worried about this. At that time, how about separating the Spreadsheet IDs?

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Could you explain how this bit of the code works please?
var values = ids.reduce((ar, [id]) => {
    try {
      var [, ...values] = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(CurrentCycleName).getDataRange().getValues();
      ar = [...ar, ...values];
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`"${id}" was not found.`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (values.length == 0) return;

Comment: @Simon Hardham Thank you for replying. About your additional question, in that part, using the retrieved values (Spreadsheet IDs) from the column "G", the data is retrieved from the specific sheet given by `prompt` and put the data to an array. When I asked your goal, you said `Your understanding is correct.`. So I used such the script. If I misunderstood it, I apologize.